# Combining constraints in a NLP

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to formulate a problem as a NLP, some of the constraints have the form " a> 0 and b > 0 and c > 0"  I was wondering if there is a way to combine those constraints into a a single one : i.e. find a function f s.t. f(a,b,c)> 0 iff a >0 b>0 and c > 0.
I appreciate your help

Comment: Not sure really what you are looking for, but $\min(a,b,c) > 0$ **iff** $a,b,c >0$.

Comment: well, I can't have min (a,b,c) > 0 be a constraint in my NLP..

Comment: Ok, then you need to more specific. I am not sure why you cannot have $ \min$ as part of an NLP.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to optimization, and usually work with LP's. Am I allowed to have min(x,y,z) > 0 as a constaint in a NLP?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. You can model $\min(a,b,c) > 0$ as $a \ge d, b \ge d, c \ge d$ and $d >0$.

Comment: It is not advisable to use $\min(a,b,c)$ in an NLP because it is nondifferentiable. It's usually (much) better to use 3 separate constraints, on $a$, $b$, and $c$. And, as @copper.hat noted, you can't use a strict inequality, so you'll have to use $a \ge d$ for some small $d$. But beyond all of that, I agree -- it's not clear *why* you want to combine the 3 constraints into 1, so shedding some light on that might help us answer better.

Comment: To add to @LarrySnyder610's comment, a broad observation is that it is usually best if you preserve as much information as possible; by combining the constraints you are losing some information.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 If this is a conic optimization problem solved by a conic optimization solver, then differentiability of the constraints is irrelevant. But it is relevant if part of a "classic" NLP" (which by the way,other than a few old-timers in optimization, means Natural language Processing, having been effectively hijacked some years ago). If entered into a modeling language or optimization front end, the solver/front end might convert convex use of min (as here) to separate constraints, but by using min, the model entry is kept more succinct.